# Solving for the points that can solve the equation $6x-3y+9z=18$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, coordinates

So I was again trying to come up with questions that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came up with this problem: $$\text{Find the points }(x,y,z)\text{ that will satisfy the equation }6x-3y+9z=18$$which I thought that I might be able to do. Here is my attempt for solving the $3$-variable equation:$\color{white}{\require{\cancel}{.}}$
$$6x-3y+9z=18$$$$-3y=18-6x-9z$$$$y=-6+2x+3z$$$$6x=18+3y-9z$$$$x=3+0.5y-1.5z$$$$9z=18-6x+3y$$$$z=2-\dfrac{2}{3}x+\dfrac{1}{3}y$$$$\cancel{18}+3y-9z\cancel{-18}-6x-9z+18-6x+3y=18$$$$-12x+6y-18z=0$$$$6y=12x+18z$$$$y=2x+3z$$$$-12x=-6y+18z$$$$12x=6y-18z$$$$x=0.5y-1.5z$$$$-18z=-6y+12x$$$$18z=6y-12x$$$$z=\dfrac{1}{3}y-\dfrac{2}{3}x$$$$0.5y-1.5z=0$$$$y-3z=0$$$$y=3z$$$$x-y-z=0.5y-1.5z-2x-3z-\dfrac{1}{3}y+\dfrac{2}{3}x$$$$-8x+y-27z=0$$$$y=8x+27z+18$$$$-8x=18+27z-y$$$$x=-2.25-3.375z+0.125y$$$$18+\cancel{27z}\cancel{-27z}+y+8x+27z+\cancel{18}=\cancel{18}$$$$y=-18-8x-27z$$However, I realized that the equation had become an infinite loop of nothingness and decided to plug it into Wolfram Alpha, which gave me$$y=3n+2x$$$$z=n+2$$And plugging this into Desmos and playing around with the sliders, we get:$$x=-8$$$$y=14$$$$z=12$$Meaning that the $(x,y,z)$ coordinate solution is$$(-8,14,12)$$

---

**My question**

---

Is the solution that I have achieved correct, or what could I do to attain it more easily?

---

---

**To clarify**

---

I have done another attempt on this question before this one, however, even though my solution was correct in this case $(2.25,-1.5,0)$, I redid the entire equation since I found out that I had accidently removed a variable when there was nothing cancelling it out in the first place.

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions — indeed, a whole $2$-dimensional plane of solutions. I cannot follow what you’ve done after the first $z=\dots$ equation; this *is* the solution, expressed in graph form. End. Wolfram Alpha gave you nonsense.

Comment: @TedShifrin So you're saying that the equation that would fulfill all possible solutions to this equation is $\left(-8+\dfrac{41}{48}a,14-\dfrac{31}{24}a,12-a\right)$?

Comment: No, I’m not. You need *two* parameters, not one. And I’ve not checked that your claimed solution is actually correct, either. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin $6(-8)=-48$, $-3(14)=-42$, $9(12)=108$, $108-48-42=108-90=18$, so my solution would be correct. :|

Comment: You were done solving when you got to $y=−6+2x+3z$. Choose any desired values for $x$ and $z$, and you get a corresponding $y$ value that makes the equation true. This is why the solution set has two parameters and is two-dimensional.

Comment: @Karl Silly. OP was done way before that. There was all sorts of nonsense in between.

Comment: @TedShifrin There is no possible way that I was done before that. $y=-6+2x+3z$ was my $3$rd step

Comment: Maybe Ted means we should be "done" upon recognizing $6x−3y+9z=18$ as the equation of a plane.

Comment: @Karl That would make sense.

Comment: No, sorry. There was so much tail-chasing I missed some of it. Once you solve for any one of the variables at the beginning, you are as done as you can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single linear equation with three variables, so there are infinitely many solutions. The solution points $(x,y,z)$ constitute a 2D plane in 3D space. These observations are the beginnings of [linear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra). Also see [systems of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations).